# Will mobile application state be intact if an app goes into background

Tags: android, ios, mobile

For Android/ARM and iOS 4 if the mobile application goes into background (e.g. if another app gets focus), will the state of the application be intact, when the it becomes active again?

Could it happend that an application automatically shuts down, if idle for some period of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, the OS may kill the application if it needs to regain some memory.  This means the `onStop()` method of your activities will be called.

See [Android Developer - activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile I figured that out myself. Conclusion for Android < HONEYCOMB => save state in onPause. For Android >= HONEYCOMB => save state in onStop. It seems that for iOS >= 4 => save state in applicationDidEnterBackground. Is all this correct?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS There two method is there...
1.applicationDidEnterBackground
2.applicationWillEnterForeground

so use this method for your purpose.